# 1 Client for multiple instances - Spring Authorization server

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have Client that runs on multiple Environments (each env have its own Domain), and have 1 Authorization server that serve all those instances.
Should i create RegisteredClient for each instance, or is it enough to create only 1 client for all instances?
thanks!

Comment: I don't know that there's one right answer to this question. It might depend on what you're trying to do. What needs to change from environment to environment. What types of environments are they? For example, are they dev, qa and prod environments? Are they regions?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I'm talking about multiple prod environments that all the clients should have same attributes (scope, redirectUri etc)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've mentioned, you only require a single `RegisteredClient`. The `ProviderSettings` and specifically the `issuerUri` are resolved from the request, so each domain would have a distinct issuer without custom configuration for each instance. See notes on the [`ProviderContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-model.html#configuring-provider-settings) in the docs.